# Overloading the equals operator with a template using Effective C++

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, weffc++

I am porting old C++ code to an Effective C++ safe version. I read about problems with this flag, but as I don't have a choice wether to do it or not, it has to be. I came along a problem with overloading the equals operator when using a template.

I tried to move the functionality from header files to the actual cpp's, but this didn't have any effect. Removing the template worked, but as the template is needed, it just showed me where the problem is.

```cpp
template <typename T1, typename T2>
MyClass& operator = ( const boost::tuple<T1,T2> & _v )
{
    //Some operations
    return *this;
}
```

Compiling this code throws the following error:

```
'operator=' should return a reference to *this
```

pointing at the exact line `return *this;`

MyClass does not inherit any other class. Is this a effc++ bug or is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Could you please explore '//Some operations'?. And btw this is the assignment operator, not 'equals operator'

Comment: Definitely seems like a bug to me. Let's confirm this with the help of a [mre].

Comment: _"I don't have a choice wether to do it or not"_ -- why not? The `-Weffc++` option is broken and buggy and gives advice that only makes sense in C++98.

Comment: My company wants the code to be free of `-Weffc++` warnings, and I am not the person to decide this @JonathanWakely

Comment: The operations just change a few class attributes, when commenting the operations out, the error doesn't change, so this doesn't seem to be related to this @mvidelgauz

Comment: Trying to be free of buggy warnings from a buggy option is a stupid policy.

Comment: An `operator=()` of `MyClass` needs to be a non-static member of `MyClass`.  You can't declare such a thing outside the class definition of `MyClass`.   Compilers tend to give cryptic error messages if you don't follow that rule - since `this` does not exist outside a non-static member it is feasible it will complain about that.

Comment: The operator is declared in the class, I just missed it in the code above. @Peter

Comment: Then you're going to need to provide a [mcve] - a small sample of code that others can feed to a compiler and replicate your symptoms.   The information you've given is insufficient for anyone to help you.